# Using Log4j2 annotation with custom generated logger

Tags: groovy, log4j2

According to http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/customloglevels.html#CustomLoggers it is possible to generate sources for a custom logger wrapper when using custom logging levels to introduce convenience methods for that custom logging level.

We are currently using the Groovy @Log4j2 annotation to inject a logger field into  classes that needs a logger.

Is is possible to combine the two - i.e. the new convenience methods should be availble through the injected logger via the annotation - using the annotation or would it require to write a new custom annotation as well?

We are currently using Log4j2 2.11.2, Spring Boot 2.1.4, Groovy 2.5.6 and Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any possibility but you could create your own annotation processor and generate the code you like to have.

https://www.baeldung.com/java-annotation-processing-builder

Comment: It's my thought as well - or at least in that direction. I think i'll follow the pattern of the Groovy implementation using AST transformations rather than implementing an annotation processor. It's a pitty that the FQDN of the logger isn't available as input or configuration of the annotation.